# Entity Framework:An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is my base `Repository` class :

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    protected RepositoryBase(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Entities = DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    public IDbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }    
    ...
    ...
    ...

    public TEntity DeleteOne(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        Entities.Remove(entity);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

When I want to call delete method it throws an exception which I'm pointing in post title. I don't know how can I solve this issue. Please note that, other answers on different topics with same error didn't solve my problem.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What does `Entities.Local.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == entity.Key)` return?

Comment: Is there any navigation property in `entity` object filled? These can cause the issue as well.

Comment: Do you get the exception at the first statement in the `Delete` method?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Yes, there is a navigation entity.

Comment: In such case you must ensure that no entity in the object graph already exists in the context. Because you are going to delete your current entity you should simply clear all its navigation properties before you change its state to deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

That's trying to attach a second copy of the entity. That's a shortcut for:

```
DbContext.Attach(entity);
DbContext.Remove(entity);
```

So your code is really:

```
public TEntity DeleteOne(TEntity entity)
{
    DbContext.Attach(entity);
    DbContext.Remove(entity);
    Entities.Remove(entity);
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

And as it's already attached it's throwing an error.

Comment: Attaching the same object twice is not a problem.